# Swap partition usage

Tags: partitioning, swap

I created a 7.5Gb swap partition when I installed UBUNTU 12.04 on my 80 GB hard disk. My system runs with 512Mb RAM. I am not sure if this SWAP partition size is right. I also would like to know if the swap partition is being utilized by the operating system. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's way too large. I'd suggest a 1GB swap partition.

Comment: One gigs is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine how much swap is used from the system type:

```
user@host:~# cat /proc/meminfo | grep Swap
SwapCached:            0 kB
SwapTotal:       2095100 kB
SwapFree:        2095100 kB
```

Comment: I got it. However, isn't there a way to get this info in GUI itself instead of having to type these long commands in the terminal. Find it quite difficult to remember the command lines.